# GitLab only builds for specific tag names

Tags: gitlab-ci

Is there a way to instruct the pipeline to only do a step for certain tags that matches a regular expression?

I would like it to do a deploy when I push a tag on the format 1.2.3 (for example). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `only` option:

```
job:
  # Use regexp
  only:
    - /^issue-.*$/


job:
  # Use special keywords
  only:
    - tags
    - triggers
    - schedules
```

See *[only/except (basic)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified)*.

Comment: As i just researched some CD/CI Features of gitlab i came acress this. Beware of one "feature":
only is not capable of combining regex and special words, so 
only:
   - /^issue-.*$/
   - tags
will trigger on any tag _and_ any tags, branches,... starting with "issue-".

As i understand this, there is no way to limit the regex to be used on only tags or only branches (correct me if I'm wrong - I really hope someone does!).

Comment: not quite sure.. what about combining it with `except: [tags]`

Comment: you probably mean - combine it with `except: -branches`

Answer (score 57):

This should only be run for refs that are not branches named matching the given regex.

```
   job:
      only:
        - /^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$/
      except:
        - branches
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with except. Unfortunately you missed the mandatory slashed at start and end of your regex. @see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only-and-except-simplified

Comment: This part of the regex is odd: `(\*|\d+)`.  Putting literal asterisks in a git tag would be unconventional, at best.

Answer (score 18):

You can also make use of [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules):

```
job:
  script: echo "Hello, World!"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/'
```

Comment: As `only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.` ([source](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)) it appears [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) is now the way to go.

Comment: You can also put the suggested regex from semver.org here to be fully conform.

https://semver.org/#is-there-a-suggested-regular-expression-regex-to-check-a-semver-string